# Safari replaces some text with an A

Tags: macos, safari, font

I recently reinstalled my computer because I got a new hard drive. After the reinstallation my Safari started to act weird.

It replaces some text with an A in a box, please see images below.

[image: screenshot of a Google search]

[image: screenshot of StackOverflow]

I use OS X 10.8.5 and Safari 6.0.5.

I hope that someone can help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol you see, letter A in a box with rounded corners, is most probably the generic glyph is used in some fallback fonts like [LastResort](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/lastresort/index.htm). It means the data contains some Ascii (Basic Latin) character, and for some reason, a fallback font is used.

It’s more difficult to say. On the pages in the screen shot, the text rendered that way have Arial set as the primary way, so it almost looks like Arial was somehow replaced by LastResort in your computer. But this would affect the page more widely, and your use of the computer in general, so it’s probably something in Safari.

I would first try re-installing Safari.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm not a mac guru but what i know it's not possible to reinstall Safari, think I need to reinstall the whole OS. I will try to update to Mavericks and see if that will solve my problem.